# How to check device and wifi capability for Multicast / Google Nearby Connection

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-nearby

I'm playing around with Google Nearby Connection API for Android and it basically works well.

But I noticed that some WIFIs don't support Nearby Connections. (I guess because they don't allow multicast messages.) And I also read that some devices can not use multicast.

For those devices I want to show a message in my App like this:

1. "Sorry, your device is not capable of connecting via Google Nearby Connections"
2. "Sorry, your Network does not support connecting via Google Nearby Connections. Please try to use another WIFI!"

**So my question is:**
Is there a way to programmatically find out whether the device and network are capable of connecting with Nearby Connections?